# Parallel arrays with string and integer

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, integer

I am having difficulty with a problem for my Visual Basic 2012 class. The instructions are below:

> Month\Days Program: 
>   The application will use two parallel arrays: a string array that is initialized with the names of the months, and an Integer array that is initialized with the number of days in each month. When a button is clicked, the application will display its output in a list box.

Here is my code so far. How do I program it so that the month will be assigned to the correct number of days? Thanks for any help!

```
Private Sub btnclick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnclick.Click
    'displays the month associated with the number of days entered by the user
    Dim months() As String = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
    Dim days() As Integer = {31, 28, 30}
    Dim searchfor As String
    Dim subscript As Integer

    'assign the month to a variable
    searchfor = txtbox.Text

    'search the month array for the number of days
    'continue searching until there are no more array
    'elements to search for or until the months are found
    Do Until subscript = months.length _
        OrElse searchfor = months(subscript)
        subscript = subscript + 1
    Loop

    'determine whether the days were found in the months array
    If subscript < months.length Then
        dayslabel.Text = days(subscript).ToString
    Else

    End If

    txtbox.Focus()

End Sub

Private Sub txtbox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtbox.TextChanged
    txtbox.SelectAll()
    dayslabel.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Why did you make `days()` three elements long and not 12?

Comment: I believe they interpreted it to store the possibilities `{31, 28, 30}` and doesn't know the full details of parallel arrays

Comment: The really arent parallel if they are different sizes.  A small class to hold the name and "size" would be better, or perhaps a Tupple.

Comment: @GSerg I made it three elements long because of the three possible number of days for a month. It looks like I'm incorrect in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this is what they're aiming for:

```
    Dim months() As String = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}
    Dim days() As Integer = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
    'click event
    If months.Length = days.Length Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To months.GetUpperBound(0)
            ListBox1.Items.Add(months(i) & " has " & days(i) & " days in it")
        Next
    End If
```

> **two parallel arrays**

For any valid index *X*, the item (at index *X*) in the months array is related to the item (at index *X*) in the number of days array

Also, hint hint...

> **initialized** with the number of days in **each month**

from the moment it's created, *the number of days* array should have one item for every month

Answer (score 0):

You can get number of days by name month like this :

```
Private Sub btnclick_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnclick.Click
    Try
        Dim Year As Integer = 2016
        Dim MonthName As String = txtbox.Text
        Dim Month As Integer = DateTime.ParseExact(MonthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
        dayslabel.Text = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Message
    End Try
End Sub
```